# How do you display a literal {5+2} in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am working with Tex + MathJax.
I want to display literal {5+2} in angular 2.
While `<span ngNonBindable>{{5+2}}</span>` works fine but `<span ngNonBindable>{5+2}</span>` gives error:

```
zone.js:355Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped "{" in your template? Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.) ("
  <span ngNonBindable>{5+2}</span>
```

Please suggest how can I display literal {x+y} in angular2.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Can you please try to add `ngNonBindable` to a parent element instead of the element where you want it to be applied?

Comment: I guess you could use `{{ "{5+2}" }}` but I it's not the same as using `ngNonBindable`.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, adding ngNonBindable to parent still not parsing {5+2}

Comment: What Angular2 version are you using?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, "@angular/common": "~2.0.0", It is final version I think. Can you please reproduce the problem at you end in some plnkr etc.

Answer (score 2):

If ngNonBindable directive is not working for you, you can use string literal

```
<span>{{'{5+2}'}}</span>
```

Or you can escape curly brackets:

```
<span>&#123;5+2&#125;</span>
```

List of HTML escape characters:
http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php

Comment: Though it is working for normal string, it is not working in Tex/Latex input for MathJax